# Python for loop with condition

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python (have a C++ background). I have a function in my Python code that returns an array of some objects (**on which I don't have any control**) like below:

```
def _get_object_array():
    object_array[]
    # Magically get array contents from somewhere
    # The objects have some fields like id, name etc.
    return object_array
```

Then in another function I call `_get_object_array()` to retrieve only the id's of the objects returned.

What I have is following:

```
id_array = []
id_array = [x.id for x in _get_object_array()] #<--
```

But I don't want the ids of all the objects in the returned array. Instead I only want to store the ids for array elements which meet some criteria (e.g. id is an even number?)

Is there a way I can do that in the same line marked with `<--` like below (which btw is just a pseudo code)?

```
id_array = [if x.id % 2 == 0: x.id for x in _get_object_array()]
```

Thanks in advance.

/R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep: same words, you just got the syntax backwards.

```
id_array = [x.id for x in _get_object_array() if x.id % 2 == 0]
```

List comprehensions are amazing, and can do a lot more work than most people realise; [have a read of the relevant PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Comment: Also remember if you are going to iterate over the array a single time later, you can use () instead of [] to create a generator that calculates the values on the fly instead of all at once, it saves memory that way.

Comment: Yeah, that's also great for using `any` and `all`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you were very close:

```py
id_array = [x.id for x in _get_object_array() if x.id % 2 == 0]
```